# Is there a way to detect npm is installing package?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a webpack running in watch mode. When I installing packages with npm webpack still try compiling the source code which wired lead to npm deleting some packages under `node_modules` folder. I've already added `node_modules` to `watchOptions` to ignore it but not work. So I want to stop watching while npm installing packages and resume watching after installation.

EDIT:
I found that when `npm install` package. npm will create a .staging folder under node_modules and remove it after installation. So you can use `fs.watch` on that folder to detect npm installation.

BUT, even after I stop webpack watching when npm installation detected, most packages in node_modules still got deleted.

Comment: Why not just stop Webpack while you're installing things?

Comment: @jonrsharpe cause the building process is about 20 seconds or more even after optimization and updating packages is very often.